# Access sub folder of module in HMVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I have a sub folder for uploads in my module. I am using HMVC extension for codeigniter. The structure of my application is following:
modules
--mymodule
----/controllers
----/models
----/views
----/uploads
-------/images

How can I access the images folder using URL?

Comment: I do not think it is recommended for having uploads that folder in modules I would place it in main directory because application folder is protected I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `uploads` folder outside of `application` folder(root directory).

so you can access

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/images/Logo.png" alt="">
```

> I don't think this works. Just a tip

If folder inside application folder you can use `APPPATH`

```
<img src="<?php echo APPPATH ?>uploads/images/Logo.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you. I placed the folder in root directory.